# cabal dependency build fails

Tags: haskell, build, cabal

hello I am new to haskell/cabal so this might be a stupid question but i couldn't find it anywhere.
When I try to build a cabal package it correctly list the dependencies.
cabal build main

```
In order, the following will be built (use -v for more details):
 - dependency-1.0
cabal: Failed to build dependency-1.0
```

so then I do

```
cabal build dependency
```

and it build fine listing the correct version. I go back to cabal build main and it still fails. And what is more weird when I go to build the dependency again it says build required

There are 2 questions. Why would it fail in the main if it build by itself just fine. And also even if I run cabal build dependency over and over it always says build required, like it isn't caching anything? Is this normal?

Comment: Regarding the first question: What's the full command and the resulting error message?

Comment: Also, what is "main"?

Comment: cabal build [main] is the entire command. ITs not the [main], its a package called "plutus-playground.server"

Comment: Unfortunately I don't think there's enough information here to answer your questions. In particular, it's unclear how to reproduce the problems you're seeing.